# Error ng-areq in my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm a begginer of angularjs

I have front end code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scope Data</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="aplikasi.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="BukuController">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li  ng-repeat="b in bukus">
                    <p>Judul : {{b.judul }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And js

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);

function BukuController($scope){

    $scope.bukus={
        "java":{
            "kode":"java",
            "judul":"Java EE Programming",
            "penulis":"Rahman dkk"
        },
        "javascript":{
            "kode":"javascript",
            "judul":"Javascript 2014",
            "penulis":"Rully"
        },
        "net":{
            "kode":"net",
            "judul":"Advanced .Net platform",
            "penulis":"Rloio"
        },
        "php":{
            "kode":"php",
            "judul":"Php legacy code",
            "penulis":"Ruzman"
        }
    }

    $scope.selectedBuku=null;

    $scope.setBuku=function(code){
        $scope.selectedBuku=$scope.bukus[code];
    }

}
```

but if i'm running index.html on browser, it shows blank and see error

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=BukuController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at Error (native)
>       at file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:6:417
>       at Rb (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:19:510)
>       at sb (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:20:78)
>       at $get (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:75:396)
>       at file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:57:100
>       at r (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:7:408)
>       at B (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:56:471)
>       at g (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:51:335)
>       at g (file:///D:/training/di%20luar%20lussa/belajar/app/angular.min.js:51:352)(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.min.js:102$get @ angular.min.js:76$get.n.$apply @
>   angular.min.js:126(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:17e @
>   angular.min.js:36d @ angular.min.js:17uc @ angular.min.js:18Jd @
>   angular.min.js:17(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:250a @
>   angular.min.js:164c @ angular.min.js:32

What is my problem? Please help me 
Thanks before ,

Answer (score 1):

fordg, your code seems to be working as-is (no modifications, no console errors) here: https://jsfiddle.net/b4ox1Lnt/

it could perhaps be a simple reference location issue with the .js files (in your HTML `script` tags) -- Your HTML tags suggest that the index.html and both .js files are in the same folder, is this true? (also check that the .js filenames are correct)

GL!